# How not to use set for ID but need it for constructor of Object

Tags: php, mysql, database, constructor, auto-increment

I'm trying to make a project where I have a DataBase with Mysql, and I'm adding and updating/deleting data from it.

The thing is, I'm supposed not to use a set for the ID, because I'm using AUTO_INCREMENT when I make the INSERT into de DB.

Then, because of that, when I get back the data from de DB I convert it to an array of objects, but I don't know how to do it without using the setId(). Well, maybe with the code you'll understand more what I'm trying to say.

This is how I send the INSERT into the DB (This code is at the controller):

```
// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO db_musics (name, band, dateBirth, type) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssi", $name, $band, $dateBirth, $type);
```

Then the problem with converting the returned array from DB into the appropiate object (this is part of the code from the function to get the DB):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      switch ($row["type"]) {
        case 1: #Vocalist
          $ms = new Vocalist($row["id"],$row["name"],$row["band"],$row["dateBirth"]);
          break;
        case 2: #Guitarist
          $ms = new Guitarist($row["id"],$row["name"],$row["band"],$row["dateBirth"]);
          break;
        case 3: #Drummer
          $ms = new Drummer($row["id"],$row["name"],$row["band"],$row["dateBirth"]);
          break;
        default:
          $ret[1] = 3; #Estat de l'operacio, error al array
          return $ret;
          break;
      }
      array_push($arrayMusicsObjectes, $ms); #Inserir cada music al array
    }
```

And here comes the real problem, the constructor:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__.'/MusicAbstract.php');

class Drummer extends MusicAbstract{

  public function getInstrument(){
    return 'Drum';
  }

  public function __construct($id, $name, $band, $dateBirth){
    $this->getId();
    $this->setName($name);
    $this->setBand($band);
    $this->setDateBirth($dateBirth);
  }
}
```

**So here at the constructor, I get the $id but how can I put it into the object?**

Hope I have explained myself properly (English is not my mother language).

Thanks in advance ! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to `getId()` in constructor instead of setting it?

```
$this->getId();
```

shouldn't it be replaced with `$this->setId()` 
?

Of course if you have `setId()` method in your model

UPDATE

so if you dont need to use `setId()` method, simply remove this line and simply attach property this way: `$this->id = $id`

Comment: One of the conditions to develope this project was to do it without setID() but I'm beginning to think it's a mistake, or maybe I'm leaving something to do it like that :S

Comment: so if you dont need to use `setId()` method, simply remove this line and simply attach property this way: `$this->id = $id`

Comment: PERFECT ! I have tried something similar but It haven't worked, it's throwing me an error anyway. This is doing it working now. Lot's of thanks my friend :D

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor you should have `setId` method:

```
public function __construct($id, $name, $band, $dateBirth){
    $this->setId($id);
    $this->setName($name);
    $this->setBand($band);
    $this->setDateBirth($dateBirth);
}
```

For the case when you're creating new object to insert to database and you want to utilise autoincrement id, you should set id as `null`:

```
$drummer = new Drummer(null, $name, $band, $dateBirth);
```

Comment: Yeah ! I know I could do it like this, making the setId like I've done with the other params, but I've been told not to use the setId(). So here is where the problem comes. Maybe it's a mistake of the instructions, I'll have to wait until tomorrow, then I'll be able to ask about it. Thanks anyway ! It'll be the correct answer if I have to do it with setId :D